# How to custom install compiled from source grpc?

Tags: grpc

I'd like to compile grpc with all the submodules from source on Ubuntu and install it into a specified location other than /usr/local

What is the way to specify this location for the supplied Makefile (similar to the --prefix option for configure scripts) ?

Answer (score 6):

You can override the `prefix` make variable:

```
make prefix=/usr install
```

Comment: Thank you. I already figured that out. I also changed the Makefile for the protobuf stuff to compile and install correctly:

Comment: ./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix="$(prefix)")
 $(Q)$(MAKE) -C third_party/protobuf clean
 $(Q)$(MAKE) -C third_party/protobuf
 $(Q)$(MAKE) -C third_party/protobuf install



That is I added -prefix=$(prefix) to the configure line and added the make install command. It all built and installed correctly.